# There will get cross-domain issue when I deploy the frontend and django backend to remote server

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

Deploy the test environment to remote server.

I use python manage.py to run the development server for django backend:

```
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

and use the apache to listen the 80 port for website frontend.

So, when website request the backend, there is cross-domain issue, because the port is not same.

How to handle this issue correctly if in the development environment?  Or if this is impossible, whether only can use distribution environment to realize it?

Comment: Send CORS headers or configure Apache to reverse proxy your application.

Answer (score 0):

[django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) may help.
Install it by pip,add `'corsheaders'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`,I only add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to `settings.py` and the CORS problem is solved.